# Detect Ctrl+S ion QTextedit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

So, I'm making a QTextEdit that edits a text file. I got the loading and saving working fine with buttons. But I got the habit of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save every time I paste something into the textedit because I used that in Notepad before. So I've been trying to implement it. But I can't wrap my head around how to detect and execute my save function. Lets call it `savetext`.

I've been going around trying to get `keyPressEvent` to work, but I just don't understand how it works. So I've been pretty helpless in trying to learn it.

My heavily simplified code looks like this:

```
class GUI(QProcess):
    def init etc...
        "Button creations and connect to save/load function"
        self.textedit=QTextEdit()

    def savetext(self):
        code

    def loadtext(self):
        code
```

Now, how do I detect a key combination being detected in the `QTextEdit`, or anywhere in my program for that matter, and cause it to do `savetext`? In my case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, though I'd just love a general explanation so I could apply it to any combo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `QShortcut` and `QKeySequence`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
import sys

def slot():
    print("Ctrl+S")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
textedit=QTextEdit()
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+S"), textedit)
shortcut.activated.connect(slot)

textedit.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use QShortcut, and right now it will activate only when textedit in focus. If you want to change the behavior please take a look [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum)

Here is a example

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        foo = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+S"), self.edit, self.saveCall, context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut)

    def saveCall(self):
        self.edit.append('Please save me')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```